Caching issue in Celery
I have a scheduled task that runs every 2 days to send reminders to people who haven't read and acknowledged documents on the system. The function works fine when I run it on the shell and all the results are correct. But when celery runs the task it gives (what I believe) cahced results.
Meaning that a user has acknowledged the document but the system still sends him reminders about the document.
below is my task:
@shared_task(bind=True, autoretry_for=(Exception,), retry_backoff=5, retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 5})
def acknowledgment_reminder(self):
     customers = Customer.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)

     for customer in customers:
        log.info(customer.full_name)
        not_accepted = customer.not_accepted.filter(document__is_deleted=False, document__section__isnull=False)
        log.info(not_accepted.count())

    if not not_accepted:
        continue

    customer.send_email(email_type='not_accepted', not_accepted=not_accepted)


Can you try to use this? F ensures that database is hit. from django.db.models import F and not_accepted = customer.not_accepted.filter( document__is_deleted=False, document__section__isnull=False ).annotate(dummy=F('id'))
